# My bootstrap navbar goes off the screen to the right, but is indented from the left

Tags: html, navbar

I've got a screenshot and code of my current site:

**CODE**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>
  title
</title>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: #235a59;
    }
    a: class.navbar-brand{
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[Website Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpSDD.png)

I would like the whole navbar to stretch across the top.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there is so many mistakes in your code

#### copy paste this code its working fine

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>
  title
</title>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: #235a59;
    }
    navbar-brand{
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is the Output]

Comment: `a: class.navbar-brand{
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }` Do change in this code see my code you made some mistake. and remove <ul> tag from nav so you get batter result

Comment: He will do that "automatically" when he finds that your answer is good...

Comment: wdym "automatically" @MARSHMALLOW?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`, `top: 0px` and `left: 0px` to put the navbar in the top-left corner of the page.
Then use `width: 100%` to make it "stretching" accross the top.
So basically you'll add this to the `<style>`:

```
.navbar {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here is your full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>
  title
</title>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color: #235a59;
    }
    a: class.navbar-brand{
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar {                  /*This will do the trick.*/
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

A living demo here: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/bGVGzWW?editors=1000